# How to declare a global object in a switch statement

Tags: c++, class, object

I am having a problem, where I need to declare an object for a class based on user input. The problem is that the scope of the object is stuck in the switch statement, and I was wondering if there was a way to make it public.

```
//ask the user to choose the class of the first fighter
    cout << "Welcome to the fighting arena! Would you like the first competitor to be a FIGHTER <1>, a WIZARD <2>, a ROGUE <3>, or a RANGER <4>?" << endl;
    cin >> competitor1;
    cout << "And what is the name of the competitor?" << endl;
    cin >> name1;

    //creates an object in the appropriate class and initializes it
    switch (competitor1)
    {

    case 1:
    {
        Fighter Battler1(name1);
        break;
    }

    case 2:
    {
        Wizard Battler1(name1);
        break;
    }

    case 3:
    {
        Rogue Battler1(name1);
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        Ranger Battler1(name1);
        break;
    }
    default:
        cout << "Sorry please enter a valid number!" <<endl << endl;
        break;
    }

cout << Battler1.hp //this is undefined because of the scope
```

Yes everything is written inside the main fuction, I know the probelm is scope and just need a way to get around it.

Comment: Use booleans, set one to true, then declare the one that is true in the correct scope

Comment: You need polymorphism

Comment: You could declare a pointer at higher scope Ranger *r; then instant irate in switch-  r=new Ranger;  you would need to then do r-> instead of r.

Comment: There are several features of C++ that can be used to implement this kind of functionality: templates and inheritance. You can find more implementation in your C++ book; but C++ simply does not work in the way you want C++ to work, here.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it as you described. You will need some kind of polymorphism: an object that will change it's behavior depending on it's type.

The most straightforward way to do it would be to use a variant:

```
using Battler = std::variant<Fighter, Wizard, Rogue, Ranger>;

auto battler1 = [&]() -> std::optional<Battler> {
    switch (competitor1)
    {
    case 1:
        return Fighter{name1};

    case 2:
        return Wizard{name1};

    case 3:
        return Rogue{name1};

    case 4:
        return Ranger{name1};

    default:
        cout <<"Sorry please enter a valid number!" << endl;
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}();

// if a valid number has been chose.
if (battler1) {
    cout << std::visit([](auto& battler) { return battler.hp; }, *battler1);
}
```

Note that you need an up to date compiler, or using `boost::variant` instead. This solution might also not be the most scalable as you'll need to effectively update the `Battler` alias when adding a new battler type.

---

Also, you could use polymorphism through pointers and vtables. It require more changes to your program, but might be more appropriate in some cases:

```
struct Battler {
    virtual int getHp() const = 0;
    virtual ~Battler() = default;
};

struct Fighter : Battler {
    int getHp() const override {
        return hp;
    }
};

struct Wizard : Battler {
    int getHp() const override {
        return hp;
    }
};

// ... all other classes of Battler
```

Then, change you switch case accordingly:

```
std::unique_ptr<Battler> battler1;
switch (competitor1)
{
case 1:
    battler1 = std::make_unique<Fighter>(name1);
    break;

case 2:
    battler1 = std::make_unique<Wizard>(name1);
    break;

case 3:
    battler1 = std::make_unique<Rogue>(name1);
    break;

case 4:
    battler1 = std::make_unique<Ranger>(name1);
    break;
default:
    cout << "Sorry please enter a valid number!" <<endl << endl;
    break;
}

// if a valid number has been chose
if (battler1) {
    cout << battler1->getHp();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for bugging you over and over, but the default case leads to no return statement. The UB there should be addressed.

Comment: @StoryTeller It might not be the best, but I opted for an exception for now. I you have a better recommendation, I'll be happy to edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: Mmm.. Depends on your preferences. Maybe just `std::monostate` as a safe "default"?

Comment: @StoryTeller I opted for an optional to reflect the unique_ptr part.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a switch case at all here, instead, an array of functors, that each create a different type of fighter and return a pointer to their base, i.e.

```
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<Champion> Create( ) { return std::make_unique<T>( ); }

std::function<std::unique_ptr<Champion>(void)> createFunctions [] = {
    Create<Fighter>
   ,Create<Rogue>
   ,Create<Wizard>
   ,Create<Ranger>
};
```

Usage:

```
std::cin >> competitor1;
std::unique_ptr<Champion> Battler1 = createFunctions[competitor1];
std::cout << Battler1->hp;
```

Comment: Slick and well protected, but in this case the pointer may net be needed at all. You could create and return an Automatic variable and if the compiler's not smart enough to [elide on return](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (though I believe elision is mandatory in C++17), you can `move` it.

Answer (score 0):

If you could make the object (Battler1) global, what datatype would it be? Instance of class `Fighter`, `Wizard`, `Rogue` or `Ranger`?

The solution to your problem is this: Create a parent class (let's say, `Character`) from which all the others (`Fighter`...) will inherit: `class Fighter : Character` etc. And then, create the objects dynamically:

```
Character *battler;

switch (...) {
case 1:
    battler = new Fighter(name);
    break;
case 2:
    battler = new Wizard(name);
    break;
}

// don't forget to free the memory when not needed anymore
delete battler;
```